# Realm Browserでdefault.realmが開けない

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

RealmBrowserを使い該当のdefault.realmを指定したところ、下記のメッセージダイアログが表示され、進んでも中身が見れませんでした。

> 'default' could not be opend.It may be encrypted, or it isn't in a compatible file format.
>   If you know the file is encrypted, you can manually enter its encryption key to open it.

クエリの実行結果をprintしてみると、確実に中身はある状態です。

ファイルを開くときに何か特別な操作が必要なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

Realm Java 0.83、Realm Objective-C & Swift では0.96から、データベースファイルのフォーマットが変更されました。

この変更に RealmBrowser が追従できていないため、データベースファイルを開くことができなくなっています。
開発チームでもこの問題は認識していて、近いうちにRealmBrowser が更新される予定になっています。

更新版が公開されるまでもうしばらくお待ち下さい。

https://realm.io/jp/news/realm-java-0.83.0/
https://realm.io/jp/news/realm-objc-swift-0.96.0-beta/

Comment: zaki50さん、ご回答有り難うございます。

RealmBrowserの更新を待ってみます！

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases/tag/0.96-prerelease プレリリース版が出ましたのでこちらをダウンロードしてお試しください。